# Extjs/js multidemensional array convert to string

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm having a difficulty to construct a specific string from multidimensional array.

This is my array:
`[[{query:'number:1', operand:''},
[{query:'number:2', operand:'&&'},{query:'number:3', operand:'&&'}]],
[{query:'number:4', operand:'||'},{query:'number:5', operand:'||'}]]`

How do I construct a string from this array to become like this:

`((number:1&&(number:2&&number:3))||(number:4||number:5))`

I've create a recursive function however the result does not return as I expected. 
Here is my code:

```
function queryRecursive(queArr){
var que='';
Ext.each(queArr, function(q,idx){
    if(Ext.typeOf(q)==='array'){
        que+=me.queryRecursive(q);
    }else{
        if(idx===0){
            if(q.operand===''){
                que +=q.operand+q.query;
            }else{
               que +=q.operand+'('+q.query;
            }
        }else if(idx===queArr.length-1){
            que +=q.operand+q.query+')';
        }else{
            que +=q.operand+q.query;
        }
    }
});
return que;
}
```

Here is the return result:

`number:1&&(number:2&&number:3)||(number:4||number:5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function generates the expected output.
I added a secound parameter `addInnerBracket`, which indicates where to add the opening bracket.

Check the [working Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1job).

```
function queryRecursive(queArr, addInnerBracket) {
    var que = addInnerBracket ? '' : '(';

    Ext.each(queArr, function (q, idx) {
        if (Ext.isArray(q)) {
            que += queryRecursive(q, true);
        }
        else {
            var innerBracket = addInnerBracket ? '(' : '';
            addInnerBracket = false; // only add one inner bracket
            que += q.operand + innerBracket + q.query;
        }
    });

    return que + ')';
}
```